# Customize JW player

Tags: customization, jwplayer, skin

Is it possible to achieve the functionality as given in http://flowplayer.org/designer/ in JW player. I want my clients to customize their player lively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by making a custom skin for the JW Player. We have a SDK available on our developer wiki - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Comment: I do not want to create images and apply them as skin as my end user will not have control over the player hosted in my web server. I just want to provide the option to change the color of player and its controls. Thanks!

Comment: You would basically need to make your own wizard to do this. We don't really have anything like a wizard though for you to use for your own site though.

Comment: Thanks! I understand but I am not sure whether there are library functions available in JW player to change the color of elements?

Comment: You can't change the colors, they are just custom PNGs being served through an XML file by the custom skin.

Comment: So, it is not possible to achieve this functionality through JW player?

Comment: Yes, but you need to build your own skin. Not out of the box, no.

Comment: Please help me with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511203/video-not-playing-in-jwplayer

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess you can do it jw player 7, Create a custom css skin and serve it through php.