# Video not playing IN JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, html, video, jwplayer

I am using my own skin in JWPlayer and playing a youtube video. But the video doesnt show up.I am able to get the skin on the player.Here is the code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key=mykey";</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container").setup({
             flashplayer: "fwplayer.swf",
            file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gniYetOxCo",
             skin: "myskin.xml",
            height: 270,
            width: 480
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked @EthanJWPlayer. I have posted the answer below. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed this code from my localhost and it worked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("container").setup({
             flashplayer: "fwplayer.swf",
            file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yourVideo",
             skin: "mySkin.xml",
            height: 270,
            width: 480
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

JW Player uses the Flash player to delivery YouTube content on desktop browsers at the moment. You need to un-comment the `flashplayer` property as demonstrated in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hZVHh/

If the player skin isn't found then this can prevent the player from loading too - ensure you're referencing it correctly.

Comment: i have uncommented the flashplayer property and using skin five.xml. Now the skin shows up but the video doesnt play.

Comment: Is the included js file and the flashplayer correct? Because i have copied it from SO

Comment: The URL for jQuery is incorrect, I assumed it was just demo code anyway. Either way, you don't need jQuery for JW Player to run. If you use the debug console on your browser then it ought to tell you what's up, or you could post a link to your actual code.

Comment: Also, I've just noticed that if the URL for the skin is incorrect then this can actually cause issues. Make sure that you're referencing it properly - to use 'five', enter `five` rather than `five.xml` (http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406968-using-jw-player-skins).

Comment: writing five doesnt work. THis is my actual code only. I dont want the jquery library, so i have removed it.

Comment: Also there is nothing in console

Comment: i am able to get the skin. Now the video is not playing.Edited the question.